# Array in UITextView

Tags: iphone

I have an array`appdeligate.biblearray`. I just want to display this array in a textview. This array contains sql datas of 4 types `chapterno`, `verses`, `genisis` and `text`. i need to extract only the `verses` and display it in textview how to do this?

Comment: Your array contains only four items chapterno, verses, genisis and text?

Comment: chapterno, verses, genisis and text are arrays?

Comment: how have you added chapterno, verses, genisis and text in array ?. Do you mean that these are the four columns in database that you have fetched in an array.

Comment: @RahulSharma these are four colomns in the databse that i have fetched in array

Comment: @Nipinvarma your way is not correct, array should have entities and access column value same as property or using key(column name).

Comment: @Nipinvarma, Can you NSLog `appdeligate.biblearray` and post the output here?

Comment: @EmptyStack ok sir .please wait,let me check

Comment: Don't use array count. Use `NSLog(@"Array: %@", appDelegate.biblearray);`

Comment: @EmptyStack lots and lots of like this.."<bible: 0xb3a6ad0>",
    "<bible: 0xb3a6bf0>",
    "<bible: 0xb3a6cd0>",
    "<bible: 0xb3a6e10>",
    "<bible: 0xb3a6f00>",
    "<bible: 0xb3a6fd0>",
    "<bible: 0xb3a70e0>",
    "<bible: 0xb3a71e0>",
    "<bible: 0xb3a7300>",
    "<bible: 0xb3a7430>",
    "<bible: 0xb3a7570>",
    "<bible: 0xb3a76c0>",
    "<bible: 0xb3a77a0>",
    "<bible: 0xb3a7860>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `biblearray` has the objects of type `bible`. You can get the `verses` from `bible` objects like this,

```
bible *_bible = (bible *)[appDelegate.bibleArray objectAtIndex:0];
textView.text = [_bible verses];
```

or directly as,

```
textView.text = [[appDelegate.bibleArray objectAtIndex:0] verses];
```

If you want to display all the `verses` in the textView, you can do it like this,

```
NSArray *allVerses = [appDelegate.bibleArray valueForKey:@"verses"];
textView.text = [allVerses componentsJoinedByString:@"\n\n"];
```

`@"\n\n"` adds two new lines between the `verses`.

Comment: got the first verse of the bible,but i need to display alla the verses in the textview sir.thanks.

Comment: ohhh thats awsomeee,i got alla the verses ,but just one more help i have to separate it with space not the /n .is it possible?

Comment: sir got the answer,i put @" " instead of /n.thanks for ur help

Comment: i have another doubt,if u r free please help me to solve this here is my question [link]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631597/how-to-highlight-a-specific-text-from-a-group-of-text-in-textview

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some alteration. Create `NSDisctionary` instead. 
Take a dictionary where you are adding data from database

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *chapterno = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *verses = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *genisis = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *text = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//Add data you are getting from database  
[chapterno addObject:chapternodata];
[verses addObject:versesdata];
[genisis addObject:genisisdata];
[text addObject:textdata];

[dict  setValue:chapterno forKey:@"chapterno"];
[dict  setValue:verses forKey:@"verses"];
[dict setValue:genisis forKey:@"genisis"];
[dict setValue:text forKey:@"text"];

[chapterno release];
[verses release];
[genisis release];
[text release];
```

Take one `NSDictionary` in **AppDelegate** say **appDict** and make it equal to **dict**

```
NSMutableArray *arrVerses = [[objAppDel.appDict objectForKey:@"verses"];  
txt.text = [arrVerses description];
```

Comment: @Nitish, It seems the `bibleArray` has objects of type `bible`. More structured/object-oriented than a dictionary ;-)

Comment: @EmptyStack : Your implementation is correct too :) Its just I use dictionaries instead ;)

Comment: @EmptyStack : +1 for your answer.